# update drupal to latest version causing weird themes issues

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I have updated my drupal into latest version which is 8.1.9, i have succeded the updates, everything is seems fine except the Uninstalled theme section under **appearance** menu
it seems lots of unknown Uninstalled themes there which are not before, please refer screenshot

[image]

Comment: Did you *update* (as in 8.1.7 => 8.1.9) or *upgrade* (as in 7.50 => 8.1.9)?

Comment: @Paul i have updated from drupal 8.0.0-rc4 to drupal  8.1.9

Answer (score 0):

These themes might be introduced as part of core in new version i.e 8.1.9. Please check in themes directory for the same.

Comment: I hope its not, because as you see in the image all the themes mean to be just test themes, and i checked for theme direcory there is no such things in it

Answer (score 0):

These test themes should not appear in your UI. When creating your original site, did you use the default.settings.php or the example.settings.php as source for your settings.php?

Please check, if there is a flag activated in your settings:

```
$settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = TRUE;
```

If that's present, change it to FALSE and all the test themes should disappear.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2759227 for a similar issue on d.o.